# does not exec lazyload of objects retrieves from JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have

```
public class Customer(){

  private List<OtherObject> otherObjectList;
  ...
}
```

I get Customer object from database, if I do this

```
   customerObject.getOtherObjectList().size()
```

it will occur `LazyInitializationException` . It's OK, it there any way to "disconnect" the object retrieved from database? After get it from database, I'd like to use   `customerObject.getOtherObjectList().size()` without call LazyLoad feature and the error `LazyInitializationException` will not occur!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, you can't do that. When your collections is `LAZY`, what happens is that hibernate creates a proxy rather than actual collection. As soon as you try to access that collection through getter method, the proxy object executes a query to get the real collection from DB (this is called initialization). Having said that you can't customize this process, even if you could, a query would need to be executed to get the size and you would need an open session to do so however.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to force lazy initialization of the otherObjectList collection by calling Hibernate.initialize(customerObject.getOtherObjectList()) before the originating session closes.  Then when you access customerObject.getOtherObjectList() outside the session it will already be loaded.

If the session is closed and you don't know if lazy initialization occurred, you can check by calling Hibernate.isInitialized(customerObject.getOtherObjectList()).  At that point, if it's not initialized, then it wouldn't make sense to call .size().

Comment: But I dont want to get the records of the collecion, I need to exec the method size() wihout exec lazyload, I want to disable in this moment the lazyload feature!

Comment: If your intention is to just get a count but not actually load the otherObjectList, then you'd need to run query for that:  session.createQuery("select count(o) from OtherObject o where customer.id = :id")
      .setLong("id", customerObject.getId()).uniqueResult()